# How to block image loading for UIWebView ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiwebview

I want to use  uiwebview to load www.youku.com. But, i only want to load the plain text without images. On the other word, i want to block images for uiwebview. I have checked http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/08/18/url-filtering-with-uiwebview-on-the-iphone/ and implemented it as bellow:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
{
   NSURL *url = [request URL];
   BOOL blockURL = [url.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [url.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"jpeg"] || [url.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"png"] || [url.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"gif"] || [url.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"ico"] || [url.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"JPG"] || [url.absoluteString hasSuffix:@"JPEG"];
   if (blockURL) {
     NSURLResponse *response =
         [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:url
                                MIMEType:@"text/plain"
                       expectedContentLength:1
                            textEncodingName:nil];
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse =
          [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response
                         data:[NSData dataWithBytes:" " length:1]];

    [super storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request];

    [cachedResponse release];
    [response release];
}
    return [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
}
```

With the code listed above, i can block some images with suffix like png , gif ,jpg and so on.
However, some images have special url without suffix, such as http://g4.ykimg.com/0100641F4650B6A053C841081E2CED75B89DFC-FF09-FE48-E9A9-783C7AD8EC42. 
For these special urls, the above code will not work.
So If anyone have good ideas about how to detect whether a special url is related to an image?

Comment: I know that we can check the MIMETYPE of an url to check if it is "image/*", but how can we get the result in - (NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request?

Comment: Do you just want text, or do you want everything except images? 

I mean, instead of looking for images to block by extension, look for text and block everything else (including images with funny extensions). Not sure how to do this, but is potentially a different avenue of attack...